# how do I change the colour of a row and column of the ellipses in response to the mouse being over one of the ellipses?

Tags: java, processing

1. I've built this sketch on processing where it generates ellipses on the grid. I wanted to know how I would change the color of a row and column when the mouse hovers over it.

```
void setup()
{
  size(400,400);
  noStroke();
  fill(180,50, 50, 100);
}
 
void draw()
{
  background(255);
 
  for (int row=0; row<10; row = row+1)
  {
    for (int col=0; col<10; col = col+1)
    {
      ellipse(20 + col*40, 20 + row*40,30,30);
        if (mousePressed && (mouseButton == LEFT))
        fill (random (55));
         ellipse(20 + col*40, 20 + row*40,30,30);
      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compute the center point coordinates of the ellipse:

```java
int cY = 20 + row*40;
int cX = 20 + col*40;
```

The position of the mouse is stored  in the built-in variables [`mouseX`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseX.html) and [`mouseY`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseY.html).
The ellipses are arranged in a grid. Test whether either the x- or the y-coordinate of the mouse is in the area of ​​the grid that belongs to the ellipse. Set the color depending on the test result:

```java
if ((mouseX > cX-20 && mouseX < cX+20) || mouseY > cY-20 && mouseY < cY+20) { 
    fill(255, 50, 50, 255);
} else {
    fill(180, 50, 50, 100);
}
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```java
void setup() {
    size(400,400);
    noStroke();
}
 
void draw() {
    background(255);
   
    for (int row=0; row < 10; row++) {
        int cY = 20 + row*40;
        for (int col=0; col < 10; col++) {
            int cX = 20 + col*40;
            
            if ((mouseX > cX-20 && mouseX < cX+20) || mouseY > cY-20 && mouseY < cY+20) { 
                fill(255, 50, 50, 255);
            } else {
                fill(180, 50, 50, 100);
            }
            ellipse(cX, cY, 30, 30);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 0


Compute the center point of the center point coordinates of the ellipse:

int cY = 20 + row*40;
int cX = 20 + col*40;      could you explain this please?

Comment: @Babycakes69 Just a typo.